# Concave weakly increasing function with 0 derivative after a specific value

Tags: analysis, derivatives

I need a function (non-piecewise) that is weakly increasing over positive reals, starting at x=0 with a positive gradient but flattening at some finite d > 0.

Is this even possible to construct?